# Is it possible to repeat part of a string that hasn't been executed yet in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I'd like to know if it is possible to repeat part of a command (which hasn't been executed yet) on the same line (i.e., chained).

Let's say I want to execute this command

```bash
mkdir -p /some/long/dest/path && rsync -azP /some/long/src/path /some/long/dest/path
```

Is it possible to type only something similar to

```bash
mkdir -p /some/long/dest/path && rsync -azP /some/long/src/path /path/at/x:2
```

Obviously, `x:2` is the index in the array of the *last executed command*, so I'd like to know if it's possible to get away with chaining strings together and re-using the command at *`x`* position of the current string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the line editing function to grab the `mkdir` argument and paste it to the end of the line. (I use `vi`-style line editing so that would be very straightforward: ESC to enter editing mode, `0WW` to jump to the `mkdir` path, `yW` to yank the path, and `p` to paste it afterwards. I assume there's an equivalent in the default `emacs`-style line editing.)

Alternatively,

```
p=/some/long/dest/path; mkdir -p "$p" && rsync -azP /some/long/src/path/ "$p"
```

Or possibly, since this is an interactive session, view the `mkdir` result *by inspection*:

```
mkdir -p /some/long/dest/path
rsync -azP /some/long/src/path/ !$
```

In case you've not come across it before, `!$` is a substitution for the last argument (`$`) of the last command. It's in `man bash` (amongst others). Try this to see how it carries through:

```
date --date tomorrow
echo !$
date --date !$
```

Items are referenced from zero, so `echo !!:0` etc.

I know of no way to reference an argument in the *current* command line using such `history`-style operators.

Comment: That's okay. It's just so I won't have to type out long, tedious strings 4-5 times on the same line, so I think it's more than enough. Thanks. Do you know if i execute the command you've written, and then type a new command followed by `!$` if it then expands the string/path or if I'll have to type the path out again?

Comment: or have `a=/some/long` and then use `"$a/dest/path"` and `"$a/src/path"` as necessary. You could probably do something like `a=/some/long/dest/path` and then use `"${a/dest/src}"` for the other part (provided the substitution doesn't clash with other parts of the path). Though TBH, personally I'd just be lazy and copypaste the path with the mouse or Ctrl-K/Ctrl-Y and edit the varying part by hand...

Comment: FYI, I referenced your answer in [mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/717880/80216).

Answer (score 1):

I’m old enough to remember *hard-copy terminals*
(for you kids, imagine a printer with a keyboard)
and I believe that this editor-style command line editing
is a fad that won’t last much longer.    **:-)**

But, seriously, [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716886/80216#716889) that I’m not the only one
who has heard of `!`-style command history. 
It’s discussed in some detail in [bash(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html); see the [HISTORY](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#HISTORY) section. 
Here’s a brief summary
(i.e., a list of examples with some hints as to the generalized forms):

| syntax / example | explanation / comment |
| --- | --- |
| `!number`; `!42` | The 42nd command since you logged in. Or rather, the 42nd command in the `history` list; this gets complicated if there have been deletions or truncations. |
| `!-number`; `!-1`, `!-2`, `!-42` | Relative addressing. `!-1` is the most recent command; `!-2` is the command before that, etc. `-1` is the default in the sense that `!-1` can be abbreviated `!!` and `!-1:something` (see below) can be abbreviated `!:something`. |
| `thing1:thing2` | `thing1` modified by `thing2`. A thing can have multiple modifiers. See examples below. |
| `:number` | The *n*th word. As [roaima said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716886/80216#716889), word numbering starts at 0, so, if the previous command was `ls -l foo`, then - `!:0` = `ls`, `!:1` = `-l`, and `!:2` = `foo`. |
| `:$` | The last word. As [roaima showed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716886/80216#716889) without explaining, `:$` can be abbreviated `$`. |
| `:h` | Head; same as [`dirname`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dirname.1.html). |
| `:t` | Tail; same as [`basename`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html). |

A construct that seems to be less well known is `!#`,
to refer to *the **current command**.* 
So, your

```
mkdir -p /some/long/dest/path  &&  rsync -azP /some/long/src/path /some/long/dest/path
```

command can be typed as

```
mkdir -p /some/long/dest/path  &&  rsync -azP /some/long/src/path !#:2
```

where `!#:2` gets you the second word (`/some/long/dest/path`)
from *this* command.

And, if the `rsync` arguments are really nearly adjacent,
as your example suggests, you can go even further and say

```
mkdir -p /some/long/dest/path  &&  rsync -azP !#:2:h:h/src/path !#:2
```

where `!#:2:h:h` is an example of a thing with multiple modifiers
— `dirname(dirname(!#:2))` = `/some/long`. 
We could even take it one step further:

```
mkdir -p /some/long/dest/path  &&  rsync -azP !#:2:h:h/src/!#:2:t !#:2
```

but, if `basename(!:2)` is really, literally “`path`”,
then this is actually more typing.

Comment: "_As roaima showed without explaining,_" I got `$!` from `csh` before ever coming across `bash`. Whether it should have been `!:$` there too I don't know (and haven't looked)